# Multiple For Each cell In wsInput.Range within loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use multiple For Each command with a common loop, yes I figured out this cannot be done, and I am unsure what the best practice is to deal with the issue.  I have included the code as well.  Yes, all calculations need to be within the VB.

```
Sub CreateLocationTabs()
    
    Dim cell As Range, FirstDate As Date, LastDate As Date, dateCell As Range, TargetWeight As Single, FCR As Single, PBW As Single, CurrentWeight As Single, weightCell As Range
    Dim DailyWeightChange As Single, TotalWeightCell As Range, FeedWeightCell As Range, StartCount As Single, wsInput As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
                    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsInput = wb.Worksheets("Input")

    For Each cell In wsInput.Range("C6:C17").Cells
    
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            
            StartCount = cell.Value
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count))
            ws.Name = CStr(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value)
            
            ws.Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("Date", "Week", "Weight (f_g)", "Weight (t_kg)", "Feed (t_kg)")
            
            FirstDate = wsInput.Range("C2").Value
            LastDate = wsInput.Range("C3").Value
            TargetWeight = wsInput.Range("E3").Value
            Set dateCell = ws.Range("A2")
            Set weightCell = ws.Range("C2")
            Set TotalWeightCell = ws.Range("D2")
            Set FeedWeightCell = ws.Range("E2")
            CurrentWeight = CStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
                        
            Do While FirstDate <= LastDate
                dateCell.Value = FirstDate
                dateCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WeekNum(FirstDate)
                weightCell.Value = CurrentWeight
                TotalWeightCell.Value = (CurrentWeight * StartCount) / 1000
                                
                For Each cell In wsInput.Range("F6:F13").Cells '<< This is where my issue begins
                
                    If CurrentWeight <= cell.Value Then
                    
                        If CurrentWeight >= TargetWeight Then
                        
                            FCR = 0
                            PBW = 0.5
                        
                            End If
                        
                        Else
                    
                            FCR = CStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
                            PBW = CStr(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value)
                        
                            End If
                        
                    Else
                                                                    
                        Next cell
                                            
                    End If
                    
                FeedWeightCell = (CurrentWeight * PBW) * StartCount
                DailyWeightChange = ((CurrentWeight * PBW) / FCR)
                CurrentWeight = CurrentWeight + DailyWeightChange
                FirstDate = FirstDate + 1
                
                Set dateCell = dateCell.Offset(1)
                Set weightCell = weightCell.Offset(1)
                Set TotalWeightCell = TotalWeightCell.Offset(1)
                Set FeedWeightCell = FeedWeightCell.Offset(1)
                
            Loop
        
        End If
    
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems your `For Each cell In wsInput.Range("F6:F13").Cells` next cell is inside the `If CurrentWeight <= cell.Value Then`. Maybe try without `Else Next cell`, so remove the `else next cell`, directly `end if` then after `end if`, `next cell`. So if CurrentWeight > cell.Value it skip the FCR PBW process and directly go to the next iteration. But I think your FCR PBW variable value will keep on changing each time it meet your "IF" condition during the loop. But maybe it's that what you want ?

Comment: Also I think, if during the loop of `For Each cell In wsInput.Range("F6:F13").Cells`, if all the value from F6 to F13 < CurrentWeight, then the FCR and PBW has no value. Except that you're sure that for certain there must be at least one value inside F6 to F13 which >= CurrentWeight. The other thing, maybe try to use different variable for this loop `For Each cell In wsInput.Range("C6:C17")` and this loop `For Each cell In wsInput.Range("F6:F13").Cells` ? for example : one use `for each cell_A` and the other use `for each cell_B`

Comment: The way it works is:  the script compares the value from the CurrentWeight field and compares it to the wsInput.Range("F6:F13").Cells one at a time.  If it does not meet the criteria it will move to the next cell within the range.  The issue is, you cannot have more than one cell.Value reference with a loop, and I have two.  I am unsure how to accomplish the task another way so that each cell within the range is compared and when the criteria are met it returns the correct cdell.Offset values.

Comment: You wrote : _If it does not meet the criteria it will move to the next cell_. If it never meet the criteria, then it's expected that the FCR and PBW has no value ? You wrote : _each cell within the range is compared and when the criteria are met it returns_. Did you mean during the loop, once the looped cell meet `CurrentWeight <= cell.Value` (which will give you the value for FCR and PBW), then stop the loop (exit for) ?